# S1144 C#: Unused private types or members should be removed

Tags: sonarqube

The Sonar Rule `Unused private types or members should be removed` doesn't work efficiently when a `private` method is called from a `protected` method. Example

```
protected override void DoSomething(){
     DoAnotherThing();
}

private void DoAnotherThing(){
     //no-op
}
```

Plugin reference: `C# Plugin 5.2`

For above cases, Sonarqube detects an issue `S1144` for C# code for the method `DoAnotherThing` which is essentially incorrect

The rule is finding more false positives than real issues. How do we fix this? or there is an enhancement coming in next plugin version?

2 similar issues:

- [False Positive for Private Methods](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/S1144/sonarqube/SrrPX8g1sY4/uL0_zcJBFAAJ)
- [False Positive for Reflection Methods](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/S1144/sonarqube/GAHLx0sR48c/k5b-05HQAAAJ)

Comment: Is `DoSomething` called? Is the class sealed or is it perhaps a struct?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - are you allowed to declare `protected` members in `struct`s?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Nope, apparently not, so that's out :) I thought that was only a warning, I tend to run with "warnings as errors" so I sometimes forget which is which without that setting.

Comment: Are you telling us, or asking us for a second opinion? In the former case, please inform SonarQube http://www.sonarqube.org/

Comment: @WicherVisser is right, what is the question here?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @PunitGanshani I can't repro this on my side. Something else might also come into play here. Could you create a minimal repro? Or share some more info on your context? Is this happening in partial classes in separate files?

Comment: @WicherVisser  Well, since SonarQube is one of those companies who send people over to StackOverflow to get support, I think he *was* trying to inform SonarQube.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam - the issue occurs in public classes inherited from an abstract class. The overridden protected methods are calling the private methods which are not detected by Sonar as being called

Comment: @PunitGanshani I still can't reproduce this issue. The C# plugin uses the same rule engine as [SonarLint for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47d1049d-bb27-454e-aab8-24566c85e548). Can you repro this inside the IDE?

Comment: You should better post such issues in the Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

Comment: The discussion will be continued here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/GAHLx0sR48c/iCBMVYVUAwAJ

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is feedback about the plugin and belongs into the Google Group.